# In this python beginners tutorial, where is the error resulting in AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute '_Dog__name'?

Tags: python, object, attributes

Should you need it, the tutorial I am following is Python Programming by Derek Banas:

https://youtu.be/N4mEzFDjqtA?t=41m26s

My source code follows:

```
import sys
import os

class Animal:
    __name = ""
    __height = 0
    __weight = 0
    __sound = 0

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound):
        self.__name = name
        self.__height = height
        self.__weight = weight
        self.__sound = sound

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def set_height(self, height):
        self.__height = height

    def get_height(self):
        return self.__height

    def set_weight(self, weight):
        self.__weight = weight

    def get_weight(self):
        return self.__weight

    def set_sound(self, sound):
        self.__sound = sound

    def get_sound(self):
        return self.__sound

    def get_type(self):
        print("Animal")

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall and {} Kg and says {}".format(self.__name, 
                                                         self.__height,
                                                         self.__weight,
                                                         self.__sound)
cat = Animal('Whiskers', 33, 10, 'Meow')

print(cat.toString())

class Dog(Animal):
    __owner = ""

    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        self.__owner = owner
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_type(self):
        print("Dog")

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} tall, weighs {} Kg, says {} and is owned by {}".format(self.__name,
                                                                                self.__height,
                                                                                self.__weight,
                                                                                self.__sound,
                                                                                self.__owner)
    def multiple_sounds(self, how_many=None):
        if how_many is None:
            print(self.get_sound())
        else:
            print(self.get_sound()*how_many)

spot = Dog("Spot",65, 34, "Bark", "Bob")
print(spot.toString())
```

Comment: Why are you using leading-double-underscore names in the first place? Do you know what they do?

Comment: Thanks for asking, based on the explanation provided below, I understand that the __ notation makes the denoted attributes private to a particular class. This is to be used if it is at some point specified in the documentation by a developer or system analyst that the attributes should be. Would you say that's an accurate assessment?

Comment: They're not entirely private - you can still get at the attributes with a little extra work. The behavior with leading-double-underscore names is mostly intended to prevent accidental name collisions.

Comment: because the attrib names would be the same in classes of a superclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to this. It's to do with the variables being private.

```
    def toString(self):
    return "{} is {} tall, weighs {} Kg, says {} and is owned by {}".format(self.get_name(),
                                                                            self.get_height(),
                                                                            self.get_weight(),
                                                                            self.get_sound(),
                                                                            self.get_owner())
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Python has "reserved" the use of names starting with one and two underscores within a class. Specifically, per the section on [Private Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables),

> However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. `_spam`) should be treated as a non-public part of the API

And for two underscores:

> Any identifier of the form `__spam` (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with `_classname__spam`, where `classname` is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped.

What that means is that names like `_spam` are just named, but *you should leave them alone* unless it's your class. **But,** names like `__name` get special treatment from Python, and they are converted to `__Dog_name`.

You were trying to access `__name` from a subclass - not from within the `Animal` class that defines the `__name`. And you can't, because it's designed that way. You are forced to use the *accessor method,* `.get_type()`.

Answer (score 0):

class Dog(Animal):
        __owner = ""

```
    def __init__(self, name, height, weight, sound, owner):
        super(Dog,self).__init__(name, height, weight, sound)
        self.__owner = owner

    def set_owner(self, owner):
        self.__owner = owner

    def get_owner(self):
        return self.__owner

    def get_type(self): #return super(Dog,self).get_type()
        print("Dog")

    def toString(self):
        return "{} is {} cm tall, {} kilograms weight and sounds likes {} his owner is {}".format(self.get_name(),
                                                                                        self.get_height(),
                                                                                        self.get_weight(),
                                                                                        self.get_sound(),
                                                                                        self.__owner)
```

This code works for me

output shown as below:

king is 20 cm tall, 100 kilograms weight and sounds likes groaaw
Smart is 10 cm tall, 14 kilograms weight and sounds likes lolll his owner is birl